# PHP system() help

Tags: php, shell, command-line

I have this shell script

```
    #!/bin/sh

#############################################################
# Example startup script for the SecureTrading Xpay4 client #
# Install Xpay4 into /usr/local/xpay4                       #
# To run this script automatically at startup, place the    #
# following line at the end of the bootup script.           #
# eg. for RedHat linux: /etc/rc.d/rc.local                  #
#                                                           #
# /usr/local/xpay4/xpay4.sh                                 #
#############################################################

# Configuration options

# Path to java executable
JAVAPATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home

########## Do not alter anything below this line ##########
echo "Starting Xpay4. Please ensure the Xpay4 client is not already running"
$JAVAPATH/java -jar /usr/local/xpay4/Xpay4.jar /usr/local/xpay4/xpay4.ini &
```

And I am trying to run it using,

```
system("/x/sh/shell.sh");
```

I am doing this when a user navigates to a certain page on my site, however I am getting just a white blank screen is there a way to error check with system(), I am currently using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRCIT)
```

and that is applied site wide

Comment: Are you sure you have execution permissions on that shell script?

Comment: `E_STRCIT` should be `E_STRICT`

Comment: changing `error_reporting()` levels will not tell you if the shell script actually worked or not. `error_reporting()` is only for internal PHP errors/warnings. Think of it as going to the grocery store but forgetting your grocery list. You got to the store (function call executed correctly), but you couldn't buy any groceries (error with list). The lack of a list is not PHP's problem, so it's not going to report any errors: you did get to the grocery store, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also try displaying the output from your script in case there is some issue with calling it from php:

`system("/x/sh/shell.sh", $output);
echo $output;`

Hopefully that will give you a more interesting output.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a safe-mode enabled?
As a [manual](http://pl.php.net/system) says:

> When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable.

You can check safe_mode with this script:

```
<?php
    $safe = ini_get("safe_mode");
    var_dump($safe);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
chmod +x /x/sh/shell.sh
```

and try

```
var_dump(system("/x/sh/shell.sh"));
```

system() returns false on error

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when I get a blank page it's typically a syntax error. Run your php script from the command line with -l (lower-case L) option, like `php -l myscript.php`. That will check the code for any syntax errors. Then you can continue troubleshooting from there if necessary.